# Replace items in array with elements from a different set

Tags: arrays, recursion

I'm not sure the proper way to go about this recursively.
Let's say I have two arrays

```
array1 = [a, null, c, d, e]

array2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to create a resulting array of the form

```
[
   [a, 1, c, d, e],
   [a, 2, c, d, e],
   [a, 3, c, d, e]
]
```

where each element of the second array fills in the place of null. I was able to do this just fine, but what if I have two cases of null?

```
array1 = [a, null, c, null, e]

array2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

how do I get the following?

```
[
   [a, 1, c, 1, e],
   [a, 1, c, 2, e],
   [a, 1, c, 3, e],
   [a, 2, c, 1, e],
   ...
   [a, 3, c, 3, e]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Code on Javascript:

```js
let array1 = ['a', null, 'c', null, 'e']
let array2 = [1, 2, 3]

let output = []
let cursorPosition = 0; // cursorPosition is a pointer for `array2` index
let nullPositions = []

// find nullable positions; in our case here will be 1, 4
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  if (array1[i] === null) {
    nullPositions.push(i)
  }
}

// find total expected numbers of arrays from given input and create that array
const totalArray = Math.pow(array2.length, nullPositions.length);
for (let i = 0; i < totalArray; i++) {
  output.push([...array1])
}

// replacement logic for the `null` values
for (let i = 0; i < nullPositions.length; i++) {
  cursorPosition = 0;
  // frequency: how often the cursor needs to change (depends on null position)
  let frequency = totalArray / Math.pow(array2.length, i + 1);
  let resetCursorPositionOn = frequency;
  for (let j = 0; j < output.length; j++) {
    if (j < resetCursorPositionOn) {
      output[j][nullPositions[i]] = array2[cursorPosition];
    } else {
      resetCursorPositionOn += frequency;
      cursorPosition++;
      if (cursorPosition === array2.length) {
        cursorPosition = 0;
      }
      output[j][nullPositions[i]] = array2[cursorPosition];
    }
  }
}
console.log(output);
```

#### Output:

```js
[
  ["a",1,"c",1,"e"],
  ["a",1,"c",2,"e"],
  ["a",1,"c",3,"e"],
  ["a",2,"c",1,"e"],
  ["a",2,"c",2,"e"],
  ["a",2,"c",3,"e"],
  ["a",3,"c",1,"e"],
  ["a",3,"c",2,"e"],
  ["a",3,"c",3,"e"]
]
```

**It works in any number of combinations.**

Answer (score 1):

The first case you describe is an instance of `map` pattern, and the second -- `flatMap`.

Seen otherwise, `map` is just like a loop, and `flatMap` is like a two-level nested loops, creating the result's elements one by one from the deepest level loop:

### Map:

```
      for x in [1, 2, 3]:
         let res = { result of replacing
                     the first `null` with `x` 
                     in [a, null, c, d, e] }
         yield res

             -------------------------
               [a, null, c, d, e]
             ----------------------
   1           [a,  1,   c, d, e],
   2           [a,  2,   c, d, e],
   3           [a,  3,   c, d, e]
```

### flatMap:

```
      for x in [1, 2, 3]:
         let res = { result of replacing
                     the first `null` with `x` 
                     in [a, null, c, null, e] }
         
         for x in [1, 2, 3]:
             let res2 = { result of replacing
                          the first `null` with `x` 
                          in res }                   ## res NB!
             yield res2

             -------------------------
             [  a, null, c, null, e  ]
             -------------------------
   1:        [  a,  1,   c, null, e  ],

        1      [a,  1,   c,   1 , e],
        2      [a,  1,   c,   2 , e],
        3      [a,  1,   c,   3 , e],

   2:        [  a,  2,   c, null, e  ],

        1      [a,  2,   c,   1 , e],
        2      [a,  2,   c,   2 , e],
        3      [a,  2,   c,   3 , e],

   3:        [  a,  3,   c, null, e  ]

        1      [a,  3,   c,   1 , e],
        2      [a,  3,   c,   2 , e],
        3      [a,  3,   c,   3 , e]
```

The first is like replacing each element in `[1,2,3]` with the replacement result; and the second is like replacing each element in `[1,2,3]` with the *list* of the replacement results and *appending* the resulting lists together; i.e. *splicing* the resulting lists' elements *in place*; i.e. creating the combined map, *flattened* (hence the name, `flatMap`).

Comment: s/list/array/sequence/whatever. :)